# Jbuilder to Rabl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, rabl, jbuilder

I have a strange issue using `gem gon`

it cause `.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/gon-5.2.3/lib/gon/jbuilder.rb:84: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00000000000004`

so i decided to move to `rabl`

but i need help to convert code from `json.jbuilder` to `json.rabl`

```
json.asks @asks

if @member
 json.my_trades @trades_done.map(&:for_notify)
 json.my_orders *([@orders_wait] + Order::ATTRIBUTES)
end
```